# Find the sum of the following geometric series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{5}{2^k} = \frac{5}{2}$

Tags: geometric-series

> Find the sum of the following geometric series
> $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{5}{2^k} = \frac{5}{2}$$

Attempt:

First I test with the root criterion if its divergent or convergent... $\frac {1}{2} < 1$ so it's convergent...

Now I try to find the sum and I can't get to the solution $\frac{5}{2}$.

Let's try:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{5}{2^k}=5\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}=5\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} 2^{-^k}=5\cdot2^{-2}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}2^{-k}$$

I don't know how to work with the $2^{-k}$ in here, hope for your help^^

Comment: The last sum should start from $k=0$.  But you don't need to go through all this.  If $|r|<1$, then $$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots = \frac {a}{1-r}$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{0.5}{1-0.5}=1$ should give you a hint.

Comment: Typesetting hint: you don't need to surround every symbol with dollar signs; use them just at the beginning and end of math expressions. For example, instead of `$2$$^-$$^k$`, try `$2^{-k}$`. Please have a look at the [typesetting tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} - (1 +\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} -\frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$So the answer is $5\times\frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Actually,$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty2^{-k}=2^{-2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}=2^{-2}\times2=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the answers from S.H.W and José Carlos Santos to figure out a solution if you don't know the sum $\sum^\infty_{k=0} 2^{-k}$.

$$
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=2} 2^{-k} &= \sum^\infty_{k=0}2^{-k} - 1 - \frac{1}{2} \tag{S.H.W} \\
&=2^{-2}\sum^\infty_{k=0}2^{-k} \tag{José Carlos Santos}
\end{align}
$$

If we write $L=\sum^\infty_{k=0}$ then $L-\frac{3}{2} = \frac{L}{4}$. This has as only solution $L=2$. Therefore:
$$\sum^\infty_{k=2} = \frac{L}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$$